# Add a button to a cells in a TableView (JAVAFX)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

i am trying to add an edit Button to my table. 
when i click the button it will open a window with the item selected,I tried several approaches to add the button but no one works for me.
thank you 
here is the code of my controller:

```
public class AmdinConsolcontroler implements Initializable{



@FXML
// here we add the create new user window the the event butto
private void ActionCreateNewUser (ActionEvent evt)
{
    try {
  Parent root =     FXMLLoader.load(SimpleFXapp.class.getResource("/Views/CreateUser.fxml"));
  Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
  Scene Scene = new Scene(root);
  primaryStage.setScene(Scene);
  primaryStage.setTitle("Create");
  primaryStage.show();
      }
  catch(Exception Err)
  {
   System.out.println("exception from create user");
  }
}

      // Creating the Observable list to be data for the table  
     ObservableList<Users> data1 =     FXCollections.observableList(Users.GetShortedUsrs());
    // Declaring the Table 
   @FXML
    TableView<Users> ShortedUserList;
   //Declaring the Columns of the atble  
   @FXML
   TableColumn<Users, String> ColFirstname ;
   @FXML 
   TableColumn<Users, String>LastName;
   @FXML 
   TableColumn<Users, String>UserName;
  @FXML 
  TableColumn<Users, String>Role;
 @FXML 
 TableColumn<Users, String>IsActive;
 @FXML 
 TableColumn<Users, String>LastLogin;
@FXML
TableColumn Edit = new TableColumn<>("Edit");


// Addin the edit button 




@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
    try{
        // initialzing the table column
        ColFirstname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("UserName"));
        LastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("UserLastname"));
        UserName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("LoginId"));
        Role.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("UserRole"));
        IsActive.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("IsActive"));
        LastLogin.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("LastLogin"));
       // Adding the edit Button to the 



       // setng data  the table         
        ShortedUserList.setItems(data1);
       }
  catch(Exception Err)
      { 
          System.out.println(Err.getMessage());
        }










}  




}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative solution in which the cell value property for the edit column is a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` which wraps the entire "row object". Then it sets a `cellFactory` on the column to display the button. Since the `item` property of the cell represents the whole row, the value for the row can easily be accessed using `cell.getItem()`.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class TableViewWithEditButton extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty, 150));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty, 150));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Email", Person::emailProperty, 200));

        TableColumn<Person, Person> editColumn = column("Edit", ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Person>::new, 60);

        table.getColumns().add(editColumn);

        editColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
            Button editButton = new Button("Edit");
            TableCell<Person, Person> cell = new TableCell<Person, Person>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(person, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(editButton);
                    }
                }
            };

            editButton.setOnAction(e -> edit(cell.getItem(), primaryStage));

            return cell ;
        });

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void edit(Person person, Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField firstNameTextField = boundTF(person.firstNameProperty());
        TextField lastNameTextField = boundTF(person.lastNameProperty());
        TextField emailTextField = boundTF(person.emailProperty());

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(16));


        grid.addRow(0, new Label("First name:"), firstNameTextField);
        grid.addRow(1, new Label("Last name:"), lastNameTextField);
        grid.addRow(2, new Label("Email:"), emailTextField);

        Button okButton = new Button("OK");

        grid.add(okButton, 0, 3, 2, 1);

        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        leftCol.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
        leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);
        GridPane.setHalignment(okButton, HPos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        okButton.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());
        firstNameTextField.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());
        lastNameTextField.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());
        emailTextField.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());

        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private TextField boundTF(StringProperty binding) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(binding);
        textField.setMinWidth(80);
        return textField ;
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property, double width) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setPrefWidth(width);
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final java.lang.String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can do it.

```
package tablebuttoncolumndemo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableButtonColumnDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ObservableList<EditableFileRow> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new EditableFileRow("A File"),
                new EditableFileRow("A Big File"),
                new EditableFileRow("A Lost File")
        );

        TableColumn editColumn = new TableColumn("Edit");
        editColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("editButton"));
        TableColumn fileNameColumn = new TableColumn("File Name");
        fileNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fileName"));
        TableView table = new TableView();
        table.getColumns().addAll(editColumn, fileNameColumn);
        table.setItems(data);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        root.getChildren().add(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Button Column Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class EditButton extends Button {

        public EditButton(String fileName) {
            super("Edit");
            setOnAction((event) -> {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Hey!");
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("You're editing \"" + fileName + "\"");
                alert.showAndWait();
            });
        }
    }

    public static class EditableFileRow {

        private final SimpleStringProperty fileName;
        private final SimpleObjectProperty<EditButton> editButton;

        public EditableFileRow(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = new SimpleStringProperty(fileName);
            editButton = new SimpleObjectProperty(new EditButton(fileName));
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName.get();
        }

        public void setFileName(String fName) {
            fileName.set(fName);
        }

        public StringProperty fileNameProperty() {
            return fileName;
        }

        public EditButton getEditButton() {
            return editButton.get();
        }

        public void setEditButton(EditButton editButton) {
            this.editButton.set(editButton);
        }

        public ObjectProperty<EditButton> editButtonProperty() {
            return editButton;
        }

    }
}
```

Another way you can try is to put an image instead of a button, with a listener that detects clicks. I often use that method to indicate what type of file it is using different images for pdf's, excel files, text files, and so on.

Comment: In real life though, a model class is very unlikely to have a UI component as one of its properties.