# How to add two buttons in a TableColumn of TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add two button in action TableColumn, i already read this [How to add button in JavaFX table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489366/how-to-add-button-in-javafx-table-view) and this [Add a button to a cells in a TableView (JAVAFX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139260/add-a-button-to-a-cells-in-a-tableview-javafx) but both of them use one button in `setGraphic`, so when i try to use :

```
actionFld.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<Patient, Patient>() {
    private final JFXButton editButton = new JFXButton("edit");
    private final JFXButton deleteButton = new JFXButton("delete");

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Patient patient, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(patient, empty);

        if (patient == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
            return;
        }

        deleteButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Patient getPatient = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            System.out.println(getPatient.getNom() + "   " + getPatient.getPrenom());
        });

        editButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Patient getPatient = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            System.out.println(getPatient.getNom() + "   " + getPatient.getPrenom());
        });

        setGraphic(deleteButton);//<<<---------------add button 1
        setGraphic(editButton);//<<------------------add button 2
    }
});
```

it show me just one button :

[image: just one button]

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `HBox` to add your component one beside the other for example :

```
HBox pane = new HBox(deleteButton, editButton);
setGraphic(pane);
```

result:

[image: HBox]

---

**If you have another way, i will be happy for it!**

Comment: How to do it using fxml? I want add vertical header to `TableColumn` using rotated `Label`. In java I just use `setGraphic()` with `VBox` containing `Label`.

Comment: Found it: `<graphic></graphic>`

Comment:  this is nice, because even me I don't know this, good job @OrdinaryDraft