# Add two button in one column and get the click row value javafx

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying to implement two button in one column in table view in javafx . I, am able to implement one button in one column but not able to add two button in one column .
 I got some idea from this link

[How to add button in JavaFX table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489366/how-to-add-button-in-javafx-table-view)

[Add a button to a cells in a TableView (JAVAFX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139260/add-a-button-to-a-cells-in-a-tableview-javafx)

[How to add two buttons in a TableColumn of TableView JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44696775/how-to-add-two-buttons-in-a-tablecolumn-of-tableview-javafx)

I have use the idea in the link above. However, the code is not working for me.

```
    TableColumn<Student, String> firstCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("ID");
    TableColumn<Student, String> secondCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("Name");
    TableColumn<Student, String> thirdCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("Quiz Mark");
    TableColumn<Student, String> forthCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("A1");
    TableColumn<Student, String> fifthCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("A2");
    TableColumn<Student, String> sixthCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("A3");
    TableColumn<Student, String> sevenCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("Exam");
    TableColumn<Student, String> eightCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("Result");
    TableColumn<Student, String> nineCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("Grade");
    TableColumn<Student, Student> tenthCol = new TableColumn<Student, Student>("Action");   


firstCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Id"));
    secondCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));
    thirdCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("QuizMark"));
    forthCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Assingment1Mark"));
    fifthCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Assingment2Mark"));
    sixthCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Assingment3Mark"));
    sevenCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ExamMark"));
    eightCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Result"));
    nineCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Grade"));
    tenthCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<Student, Student>() {
        private final Button editButton = new Button("edit");
        private final Button deleteButton = new Button("delete");
        HBox pane = new HBox(deleteButton, editButton);

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Student patient, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(patient, empty);

            if (patient == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
                return;
            }

            deleteButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                Student getPatient = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                System.out.println(getPatient.getId() + "   " + getPatient.getName());
            });

            editButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                Student getPatient = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            });
            pane.getChildren().addAll(deleteButton,editButton);
            setGraphic(pane);
        }
    });
```

[image: image to describe the text]

In, the action column buttons doesn't appears. Where am I doing mistake. Please anyone let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking a `cellValueFactory` the item for cells in `tenthColumn` is ***always*** `null`. Use the second argument of the `updateItem` method to determine if the row is empty or not.

Also to indicate this I'd change the type of the column to `TableColumn<Student, Void>`.

Furthermore adding the children of the `HBox` again every time the item is changed is unnecessary as is updating the `onAction` handlers, since `getIndex()` is evaluated at the time the `Button` is clicked.

You could change the code to this:

```
TableColumn<Student, Void> tenthCol = new TableColumn<>("Action");

...

tenthCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<Student, Void>() {
    private final Button editButton = new Button("edit");
    private final Button deleteButton = new Button("delete");
    private final HBox pane = new HBox(deleteButton, editButton);

    {
        deleteButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Student getPatient = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            System.out.println(getPatient.getId() + "   " + getPatient.getName());
        });

        editButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Student getPatient = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setGraphic(empty ? null : pane);
    }
});
```